# I'd like to create an array from a list, but preserve the NaNs and infs

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am parsing a datafile which contains white-space delimited text which was generated from c++.  Some of the driving computations will overflow, underflow or generate NaN's. It appears that the the strings "1.#INF00" and "1.#IND00" are not digested by numpy.array(), returning an "invalid literal for float()" error.  I have attempted making a substitution like this:

```
line = line.replace('1.#INF00','inf')
line = line.replace('1.#IND00','ind')
vals = line.split(' ')
myarray = array(vals)
```

but alas, to no avail. I have also tried 'nan' and 'NaN'. Is there some string i could substitute which float() will interpret into a nan, inf etc?  Perhaps I need to escape in some quotes?

As an aside, can you tell me how matplotlib will handle an inf?
The default solution would be to change them to NaN's when they are detected.  [I have found it demonstrated](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/nan_test.html) that matplotlib will handle those gracefully, leaving gaps in the data.  Which would be acceptable treatment for my 'inf's and 'ind's

Comment: I missed an item in this piece of code I am maintaining.  The conversion to an array was happening in a separate step from the conversion to a numeric value, and I missed this little gem: float(x) if '.' in x  else int(x), so If I had been reading the errors a little more carefully while experimenting, I would have noticed that when I *did* make the substitution, it was the conversion to an integer that was not digesting the 'inf' properly.

Comment: So I added this modification to that condition: (float(x) if '.' in x
or 'nan' in x  or 'inf' in x else int(x).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float('nan')` should return NaN and `float('inf')` should return infinity. At least that's how they work on my interpreter (CPython 2.7). It seems like things were different on some platforms (especially on Windows) back in CPython 2.5, but I doubt you're using such an old version of Python.

Maybe the problem is with numpy, but in that case you can try:

```
line = line.replace('1.#INF00','inf')
line = line.replace('1.#IND00','nan')
vals = line.split(' ')
myarray = array([float(x) for x in vals])
```

Comment: Quicker than me. `map(float, vals)` should be better, though.

Comment: After making The changes noted above, I changed the substitution on #1.#IND00 to a 'nan', which worked. Apparently there is no interpretation to 'ind'

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could just call `numpy.genfromtxt` and make use of the `missing_values` kwarg.

e.g. with this data saved as `data.txt`:

```
1 0.2 0.3 1.#INF00
2 0.5 0.6 0.7
3 1.#IND00 0.1 0.2
4 0.4 0.4 0.5
5 0.5 0.5 0.7
```

You can just do something like this (we need to set the comment identifier to something other than the default "#", in this particular case):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', missing_values=['1.#INF00', '1.#IND00'],
                      comments='somethingelse')
```

This yields:

```
array([[ 1. ,  0.2,  0.3,  nan],
       [ 2. ,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7],
       [ 3. ,  nan,  0.1,  0.2],
       [ 4. ,  0.4,  0.4,  0.5],
       [ 5. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.7]])
```